# How use if in foreach in php this my example

Tags: php

how use if in foreach if the code like this

```
<?php foreach ($images as $image) { ?>
<td><?php if (isset($image->id)) echo htmlspecialchars($image->id, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
<?php } ?>
```

i try to filter the record, like this:

```
<?php foreach ($images as $image) { ?>
<?php if($image->status == 'Y'){?>
<td><?php if (isset($image->id)) echo htmlspecialchars($image->id, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
<?php }} ?>
```

use this if

```
<?php if($image->status == 'Y'){?>
...
<?php } ?>
```

but always error

```
notice : Undefined property: stdClass::$status
```

can anyone tell me how use correct if

Comment: Can you correct your question?

Comment: yes, i have been update the question

Comment: Is the property status public? Maybe you need to use $image->getStatus() if is not.

Comment: At first be sure that your Object $image have public property status

Comment: yes sure this the public property class Pages extends Controller
{
   public function index()
    {
        $images = $this->model->getAllimages();

Comment: if i not use filter just foreach, this work

Answer (score 0):

Use empty also with the isset :

```
<?php foreach ($images as $image) { ?>
<?php if($image->status == 'Y'){?>
<td><?php if (isset($image->id) && !empty($image->id)) echo htmlspecialchars($image->id, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
<?php }} ?>
```